# MySQL: Retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

Please have a look at the below table structure.

[image]

`Client` table has the `foreign key` for `Provider` Table, which is not `NULL`. `Portfolio` table has the `foreign key` for the `Client` table, which is also not `NULL`.

I need to retrieve all the fields from the `Portfolio` table, Name of the `Client` and the `Provider` Name who is allocated to the `Client` which is referred by the `Portfolio` table..

How can I do this in SQL Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query with INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT Portfolio.*,Client.name as "Client Name",Provider.name as "Provider Name"
FROM Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client ON Portfolio.Client_id=Client.id
INNER JOIN Provider ON Client.Provider_id = Provider.id
```

Comment: It works, however is there a way that we can replace the title of the "Name" column of `Client` table and "Name" column of `Provider` table in the output? Because everyone is having the same column name `Name` ? Apart from that, it is returning all the data from all the 3 tables?

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of `*` you have write all `column duplicate name` with it `alias name`

Comment: I mean I need all the data from the 'Portfolio' but not from others. So where should I specify the column names?

Comment: Then you have to write `Portfolio.*` instead of `*`

Comment: No, what I am asking is how I can provide the columns names of `Client` and `Provider` tables.

Comment: `Client.name`,`Provider.name` etc

Comment: Can you give duplicate field name in both table so I will update my answer with that so you get clear

Comment: Yes. Client table has a field called "Name". Provider table also has a field called "Name". While I am expecting to see all the data from the `Portfolio` table, I only need to get these `Name` columns from `Provider` and `Client` table. Since both table names are same, I prefer the `Name` column in `Provider` table to be replaced as `Provider Name` and the `Name` column in `Client` table to be replaced as `Client Name`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you expected:

```
Select * from client 
  join portfolio on client.id=portfolio.clientId
  join provider on client.provider_id=provider.id
```

Comment: Since I don't need all the fields from the tables except `Provider` how can I specify the columns I require and assign `alias` to them?

Comment: @Sniper Add the name of the column you need instead of client. If you have dublicate names, you have to add the tablename as prefix.