# Select only specific columns in SQL joins and assign `alias`

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

I have the below SQL code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763379/mysql-retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables) to my previous question:

```
SELECT *
FROM Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client ON Portfolio.Client_id=Client.id
INNER JOIN Provider ON Client.Provider_id = Provider.id
```

This code return the data I need However in `Client` table, I only want the "Name" column and from the `Provider` table I only need the "Name" column, while I need all the columns from the `Portfolio` table. I also need to replace the title of the `Name` column of the `Provider` table into `Provider Name` and the `Name` column in the `Client` table into `Client Name`. So, I tried below,

```
SELECT *
FROM Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client.Name "Client Name" ON Portfolio.Client_id=Client.id
INNER JOIN Provider.Name "Provider Name" ON Client.Provider_id = Provider.id
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: `SELECT Portfolio.*, Client.Name as ClientName, Provider.Name as Provider.Name` maybe?

Comment: @N.B.: Thanks for the reply. Mind giving a full code thing pls?

Comment: This question is copied from my answer Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763379/mysql-retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: If you didn't fully understand the answer you should have asked @Sadikhasan for clarification. If you really need to ask another question then at least have the courtesy to acknowledge the source.

Comment: @ChrisF: What would you do when you have to decide whether you are going to ask the same question from the same person for 10 times, and do not understand a thing? Going to waste more time asking again and again or ask from someone else who can explain better?

Comment: @Sniper - if you didn't fully understand the answer why did you accept it? Leave a comment asking for more information or pointing out where the answer fails your case. Down-vote the answer if it's not helpful. You can always undo the vote when the answer is updated.

Comment: @ChrisF: I accepted bcs it answered to my core question. My core question was about joining tables, and the answer is correct. The second problem of alias and columns raised after that. I really don't like to down vote someone who tried to help me, not good.

Comment: @Sniper - OK, it looks like this is a follow up question. But you should have acknowledged that fact.

Comment: @ChrisF you are right. If Sniper you don't know my explanation then you can just inform me that I asked as new question.

Comment: @sadikhasan: i did ask it a lot of times and waited until you edit your answer as promised, but it is not edited. Anyway, i really dont have time to keep on discussing this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so and give new aliases to your columns,in below query i have given a short name `p` to `Portfolio`  so to select all columns from `Portfolio` you can use only `p.*` same for `Client` and `Provider` table

```
SELECT p.* ,
c.Name AS 'Client Name' ,
pr.Name AS 'Provider Name'
FROM Portfolio p
INNER JOIN Client c ON p.Client_id=c.id
INNER JOIN Provider pr ON c.Provider_id = pr.id
```

Comment: hmm..It gives the error `Unknown column 'Provider.Name' in 'field list' ` ?

Comment: @Sniper yes i have updated my answer have a look at current query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Portfolio.*, Client.Name as "Client Name", Provider.Name as "Provider Name"
FROM Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client.Name ON Portfolio.Client_id=Client.id
INNER JOIN Provider.Name ON Client.Provider_id = Provider.id
```